# First Business Date of Month Python

Tags: python, date

How do I determine the first business date of the month in python? the program I am writing is drip fed dates each loop and I need to be able to get a true/false.

I found that you can get last working business day with:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.date_range("2014-01-14", periods=1, freq='BM')
```

Thanks

Comment: by 'Business Day', do you mean weekday or some other holiday calendar?

Comment: Wouldn't the business date depend on the country where you live? What is `pd`, `event`?

Comment: So you need a boolean of whether or not the first day of the month is a business day?

Comment: I am referring to the US calendar. pd = pandas and event is simply a timestamp. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think by this you can get first buisness date of the month using [`BMS`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases):

```
In[82]:pd.date_range('1/1/2000', '12/1/2000', freq='BMS')

Out[82]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-03', '2000-02-01', '2000-03-01', '2000-04-03',
               '2000-05-01', '2000-06-01', '2000-07-03', '2000-08-01',
               '2000-09-01', '2000-10-02', '2000-11-01', '2000-12-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='BMS', tz=None)
```

Comment: unfortunately for some reason, BMS includes holidays too

Answer (score 7):

This uses the U.S. Federal Holiday calendar.  It uses a list comprehension to go through every first weekday of the month between the `start_date` and `end_date`, and then increments the day if it falls on a U.S. Federal Holiday or on a weekend until a valid business date is found.

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar

cal = USFederalHolidayCalendar()
start_date = '2015-1-1'
end_date = '2015-12-31'

def get_business_day(date):
    while date.isoweekday() > 5 or date in cal.holidays():
        date += dt.timedelta(days=1)
    return date

>>> first_bday_of_month = [get_business_day(d).date() 
                           for d in pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='BMS')]
[datetime.date(2015, 1, 2),
 datetime.date(2015, 2, 2),
 datetime.date(2015, 3, 2),
 datetime.date(2015, 4, 1),
 datetime.date(2015, 5, 1),
 datetime.date(2015, 6, 1),
 datetime.date(2015, 7, 1),
 datetime.date(2015, 8, 3),
 datetime.date(2015, 9, 1),
 datetime.date(2015, 10, 1),
 datetime.date(2015, 11, 2),
 datetime.date(2015, 12, 1)]

>>> cal.rules
cal.rules
[Holiday: New Years Day (month=1, day=1, observance=<function nearest_workday at 0x10c593578>),
 Holiday: Dr. Martin Luther King Jr. (month=1, day=1, offset=<DateOffset: kwds={'weekday': MO(+3)}>),
 Holiday: Presidents Day (month=2, day=1, offset=<DateOffset: kwds={'weekday': MO(+3)}>),
 Holiday: MemorialDay (month=5, day=31, offset=<DateOffset: kwds={'weekday': MO(-1)}>),
 Holiday: July 4th (month=7, day=4, observance=<function nearest_workday at 0x10c593578>),
 Holiday: Labor Day (month=9, day=1, offset=<DateOffset: kwds={'weekday': MO(+1)}>),
 Holiday: Columbus Day (month=10, day=1, offset=<DateOffset: kwds={'weekday': MO(+2)}>),
 Holiday: Veterans Day (month=11, day=11, observance=<function nearest_workday at 0x10c593578>),
 Holiday: Thanksgiving (month=11, day=1, offset=<DateOffset: kwds={'weekday': TH(+4)}>),
 Holiday: Christmas (month=12, day=25, observance=<function nearest_workday at 0x10c593578>)]
```